# From name and Sender Authenticated domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

Once the Sender Authentication Domain is defined on SFMC, does it mean we can create any FROM NAME we want with that Sender Authenticated Domain, even if that email address does not actually exist ? (Of course, in the Sender profile, we would set up a real existing reply-to-address).
If it is possible, would there be any deliverability issues related to that process ?

For example, my Sender Authentication Domain is "enterprise.com". Can I create any FROM NAME like news-abc@enterprise.com and use it in the sender profile (even if news-abc@enterprise.com is not a real email address, but just an address created as FROM NAME for the email sent) ?

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the "authenticated domain" after the @ you can pretty much do what you want with the so called localpart (everything before the @). The same is true for "registered domains" but those lack important deliverability features.
You, of course, have to stick to standards for valid email address formats but otherwise this is pretty flexible. [Read this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_domain_verification.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to understand the differences and implications.

The address you create in from address management or in sender profiles can be understood as a virtual address that only exists for outbound branding purposes .

You cannot send emails to this address, however. Inbound email is only processed by marketing cloud when the reply function of an email client is used. Replies do not rely on the address itself but on specific reply-to path (tied to the send job and subscriber) that is sent in the header of an email you send with marketing cloud. At this point it gets very technical but [this website](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_from.htm) has some easy to grasp explanation of this.

Reply Mail Management is used to configure this behaviour in marketing cloud, e.g. to define real addresses where those replies should be forwarded to. This can be account wide or specific to a sender profile.

As there is quite a bit that you can do with Reply Mail Management you should read the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to get familiar with the concepts and options.

Comment: Thank you very much! So in the RMM, in the Reply to/Forward to field, we can set up any existing internal email so that the replies to the email are forwarded to that internal email address ? No need to use an email with the specific SFMC Sender Authenticated domain ?

Comment: Yes. This is the way to go

Comment: SFMC allows to manually verify From email address by sending and email to that address so that we can click on it and verify the address. Yet, it is "safe" in term of deliverability to do so if the manually verified address does not have the same domain name than the SFMC Sender Authentication domain ?

Comment: No, those email addresses can experience deliverability issues as the marketing cloud email gateways are not verified for sending emails in the name of this domain (this is one major part of the SAP). This is especially critical if the domain you would be using published a SPF record that governs which servers can send emails. In general you should use those email addresses only for testing purposes and never for live sends to actual subscribers.